# Finishing a sentence with て

Tags: grammar, て-form, casual

来年、フルマラソンに挑戦しようと思って
Next year, I'm thinking of trying to run in a (full) marathon.

Hopefully an easy one for you all. I'm curious why this sentence ends in 'て' and not 'ている/ています'.
My (uneducated) guess would be that perhaps in casual / spoken Japanese, the 'いる／います' is dropped.

Or is there a nuance / mood provided by it?

Thanks for your help!